# Why I cannot go to a specific link. I'm using Jquery Ui's tab

Tags: jquery-ui

Why I cannot go to a specific link with my sign out? I'm using jquery's ui tab on this. And solution or suggestion on this situation? or it is not possible?

JS CODE: `$('#tabs').tabs();`

```
<div id="tabs" class="login-tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Profile"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Messages">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Notifications">Notifications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Find">Find Friends</a></li>
            <li><a href="destroy.php">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="Home">

        </div>
        <div id="Profile">

        </div>
        <div id="Messages">

        </div>
        <div id="Notifications">

        </div>
        <div id="Find">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the anchors real href attributes, like this:

```
<div id="tabs"> 
<ul> 
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li> 
    <li><a href="messages.php">Messages</a></li> 
</ul>
```

​
This will by default try and load those pages via AJAX into the corresponding tab. To prevent this behavior, just change the window.location  yourself in the select event , like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
select: function(event, ui) {
   window.location = $.data(ui.tab, 'href.tabs');
}
});​​​​​​​
```

for one link alone, you can try this...

```
if(parentID == '#ui-tabs-3') //The value of var parentID
{
 $('#tabs').each(function() {
      if($(this).attr('href') == parentID)
      {
          $(this).bind('select', function() {  
              window.location = $.data(ui.tab, 'href.tabs');
          });
      }
     });
}
```

Comment: what if just for my sign out tab?